# Why doesn't my regex work with Validators.pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have a form that I want to **only** allow letters, spaces, and an apostrophe. I have a Validator with Angular:

```
Validators.compose([
  AppValidators.required,
  Validators.minLength(2),
  Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'),
]))
```

The first problem is that if I were to do

```
Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z ]*/)
```

The validation wouldn't work at all.

Otherwise I've tried things like

```
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z\' ]*')
Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z' ]*/)
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z\s']*')
Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z\s']*/)
```

But the validation doesn't seem to work. According to [regexr](https://regexr.com), `[a-zA-Z' ]` seems to be what I want, but the validation still doesn't work.

EDIT:

I've tried users Thefourthbird and Brandon's answers (and while appreciate it), it doesn't work in the sense that it's still doesn't think it's valid.

I've logged the `FormControl` out here:
`console.log(this.member.control.firstName)`:

```
{
  // ....
  errors: {
    pattern: {
      actualValue: "O'Reilly",
      requiredPattern: "/^[a-zA-Z ']+$/"
    },
  },
  pristine: false,
  status: "INVALID"
}
```

Comment: Are you failing to escape your apostrophe?  It's unclear from your question what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Does \ not escape the character? "Doesn't work" means the validation from the regex.

Comment: Try using anchors `^$` and repeat the character class 1+ times `^[a-zA-Z' ]+$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've tried this suggestion and it seems to not be valid when i try to add an apostrophe.

Comment: Can you give an example for which it is not valid?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a RegExp object with the pattern validator. On occasion when using strings I've seen the validator behave unexpectedly.

For the pattern itself, `^[a-zA-Z ']+$` should suffice, so:

```
...Validators.pattern(new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z ']+$/))
```

should get you going. RegEx validator: https://regex101.com/r/W35zae/1

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question with your answer to try to give more insight, but it doesn't seem to work neither

Comment: The RegEx itself is matching the string provided: `O'Reilly` if you check it against RegEx101, so I don't think that's the reason why your control isn't registering as valid.

Comment: I've been working with Angular since beta 2, and as I mentioned, I've seen some very strange behavior when using the pattern validator with RegEx strings. When using RegEx objects, the validators work as expected every time. I've written unit tests to validate this in my applications.

Comment: what's strange is that I'm doing exactly what you're doing and adding Validators.pattern(new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z ']+$/)) and the logs are showing that.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can find some time to make a Blitz and see what else might be affecting those validators together.

Comment: So I failed to mention that this is an ionic app. I had to weirdly restart my local server and close all instances of the iOS app and now it works. I'll accept your answer. thank you so much.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have any experience with Ionic, so I'm not sure why that might have happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straight-forward solution is to use a pattern validator instead:

```
<input name="firstName" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z' ]{2,}">
```

See: https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator

Here are some implementation samples: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example (formControl, ngModel, etc.)